# How to offset a time value in Simulink?

Tags: simulink

I've been trying to calc dy/dt= 2y/t, y(1)=1 on Simulink.
I adjusted the IC=1 on the integrator but of no avail as it keeps throwing me an error "divisibilty by 0" . I just need to offset t=0 in the equation and run from t>0.
How do I?

[My model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4l7u.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the configuration parameters, you can set start time > 0 :
[image]